# Where was Alastor Moody during Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince?

Tags: harry-potter

Where was Alastor Moody during *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*?

He did survive the Battle of Department of Mysteries in *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*, and he somehow disappeared in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, and re-appeared again at the start of book *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*.

Why was he missing/not mentioned?

Comment: Probably having a pint with Dedalus Diggle and Hestia Jones... oh yeah ... and Voldemort of course, who doesn't appear in HBP either (except in Pensieve flashbacks of course)...  Alastor most likely just did other things for the Order that had him not cross paths with Harry, so he doesn't appear in the narrative.

Comment: The books are written from the perspective of Harry. While there is the odd chapter here and there that isn't, it mostly is. This is one of the reasons why the books are so good: instead of creating a wikipedia article basically or a map of where every character is at any point in time, we mostly only know what Harry knows. That means mystery, immersion and adventure. I believe the correct answer to your question in the spirit of the books is: where do you think he has been?

Comment: Please try phrasing your question title as an actual question. That would greatly improve your questions. So far, other users have edited it for you. Please try doing it yourself next time.

Answer (score 10):

Alastor Moody does in fact appear once in *Half-Blood Prince*, at Dumbledore's funeral (my emphasis):

> An extraordinary assortment of people had already  settled into half
>   of the chairs; shabby and smart, old  and young. Most Harry did not
>   recognize, but a few  he did, including members of the Order of the 
>   Phoenix: Kingsley Shacklebolt; **Mad-Eye Moody**;  Tonks, her hair
>   miraculously returned to vividest  pink; Remus Lupin, with whom she
>   seemed to be  holding hands; Mr. and Mrs. Weasley; Bill supported  by
>   Fleur and followed by Fred and George, who were  wearing jackets of
>   black dragon skin.

The reason for his otherwise lack of appearance is probably that he was not present (or his presence was unimportant) at the various events portrayed in the story. Most of the book takes place at Hogwarts, where Moody would not be expected to appear. Even though Hogwarts is under the guard of aurors that year, Moody is an *ex*-auror; moreover, Harry rarely saw the aurors that were there anyway.

In the small part of the book that takes place elsewhere, even though we never see Moody we almost see him. When Harry arrives at the Burrow, we find out that Moody is coming for dinner on the weekend:

> “Dear, why not come to dinner at the weekend,
>
> Remus and Mad-Eye are coming — ?”

However, the weekend dinner is apparently not an important enough part of the story for us to actually see it. The same is probably true of other events where Moody would have been present throughout the year.